# Reassigning element of a list inside a list

Tags: python, list, variable-assignment

I'm trying to modify the list of lists:

```
list = [['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]
```

in particular when I assign `list[0][1]='X'`, `list` is now:

```
[['0', 'X', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', 'X', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', 'X', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', 'X', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', 'X', '0', '0', '0', '0']]
```

instead of just reassigning the second element of the first sub list, it reassigns the first element of every sub list. I don't understand why this is happening. Does anyone know?

Comment: This is because of how you created `list`. Please show how you did that.

Comment: Because your `list` contains multiple references to the same other list.

Comment: This is a dup of a few dozen questions on SO (I'm searching for the best one), plus [an entry in the official Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list).

Comment: [Two-dimensional list wrongly assigning values in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667942/two-dimensional-list-wrongly-assigning-values-in-python/18667977#18667977) is another nice one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have created `list` like so:

```
list = [['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']] * 5
```

Doing this creates a list with five *references* to the *same* list object:

```
>>> list = [['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']] * 5
>>> id(list[0])
27391360
>>> id(list[1])
27391360
>>> id(list[2])
27391360
>>>
```

So, when you modify one sublist, they all get changed.

---

To fix the problem, use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead:

```
lst = [['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'] for _ in range(5)]
```

Unlike your current code, this solution will create a list with five *unique* sublists. Consequentially, changing one will not affect the others.

Also, I changed the name of your list to `lst` to avoid shadowing the [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list).  You should never create a name that is the same as a built-in.

---

Note that you could also write:

```
lst = [['0'] * 6 for _ in range(5)]
```

Doing `['0'] * 6` is not a problem here because strings are [immutable objects](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#immutable) in Python.  So, `['0'] * 6` creates a list with six unique string objects.  Lists however are [mutable objects](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#mutable) and therefore cannot be created like this.

Comment: `lst = [ 6*['0'] for _ in range(5) ]` more succinctly.

Comment: @khelwood - Good idea.  I'll mention it.

Comment: Thanks guys, problem solved. One question though. if the list ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'] is not always the same but it is stored in some variable a, how do you rewrite the part of the "for _ in ..."?

Comment: @JavierRabba - You can make a copy of the list by putting it in `list`:  `lst = [list(a) for _ in range(5)]`.  Although I personally would probably use slice notation: `lst = [a[:] for _ in range(5)]`.  It may not be as readable to some, but it is more concise and generally faster.